# Install php mapscript on ubuntu 12.04 PHP 5.4

Tags: mapserver, ubuntu, php

I follow this website : http://blog.geoghana.com/2013/06/28/setting-up-lampp-linux-apache-mapserver-php-postgresqlpostgis/ to install mapserver and the php extension on my ubuntu 12.04 64bit and PHP 5.4 system (i use this ppa https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-oldstable). I almost succeed until i have a problem on installing php5-mapscript :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mapscript
```

Here is the message on my linux terminal:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    php5-mapscript : Depends: phpapi-20090626